# Angular 2+ HttpIntercept: wait for token from server before returning intercept function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I know that this question has been addressed in one way/shape/form before, but I've reviewed all the questions and answers I can find, and still I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

HttpIntercept.intercept has to return next.handle(request).  However, I need it to wait (I know "wait" is a dirty word in front end) for the bearer token to come back from the server before it can return.  I can't for the life of me find a pattern that accomplishes this.  The intercept function cannot return until we have made a trip to the server to get a bearer token.

If this has been answered, I apologize, please provide me the link to the appropriate answer.

Non-working example (function returns before token is appended):

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token: string;
    this.auth.getToken().subscribe(response => {
      token = response['access_token'];
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted your code

Comment: Never mind post says token is coming from server

Comment: @VincentNguyen token is generated by the server.

Comment: Try putting the return in the third callback argument of subscribe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `switchMap` to return `Observable` from anther `Observable`.

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token: string;
    return this.auth.getToken().switchMap(response => {
      token = response['access_token'];
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });

       return next.handle(request);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: return next.handle(request) returns the function inside switchMap, not the intercept function

Comment: yes, but `return this.auth.getToken().switchMap()`  => this is a `Observable`

Comment: Sorry for missing that.  Ok so switchMap will return what it's argument returns?  About to continue the mock implementation.  I haven't even finished this enough to test it yet

Comment: `SwitchMap` will return `next.handle(request)` which means `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

Answer (score 2):

I can think of something like:

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth.getToken()
        .map(response => request.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${response['access_token']}`}}))
        .switchMap(request => next.handle(request));
  }
}
```

Although I am not sure it would work.

Comment: This is the cleaner answer.

Comment: With this you can get rid of the local `token` variable

Comment: this.auth.getToken() needs to return an Observable<HttpRequest> (httpClient.post) not <HttpEvent>

Comment: `switchMap` to `next.handle(request)` should change the type of Observable to `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`, at least as per what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler is being called synchronously while your request is asynchronous.

As you need to return an observable take a look into the `flatMap`/`switchMap` operator from rxjs, it would look something like:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token: string;
    return this.auth.getToken().flatMap(response => {
      token = response['access_token'];
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(request);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok I had considered this, but for the HttpInterceptor interface to be implemented, the intercept function must return an Observable<HttpEvent<any>>.  Should I just return a "dummy" observable?  Will that cause the request to go out before the interceptor finishes its work?

Comment: Right I totally missed that

Comment: This seems like a very common task (getting a token from a server and appending it to API calls).  I'm surprised that it's been so difficult for me to solve or find an existing pattern.

Comment: @SeanIvins What I did in my app was get the token and store it in localstorage first...but let me try to write an answer for you to attempt

Answer (score 0):

Try returning in the Observable completed function:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token: string;
    this.auth.getToken().subscribe(response => {
      token = response['access_token'];
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    },
    err => { console.log(err) },
    () => return next.handle(request) // this is called after the completion of observable
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile as the method is not returning anything

Comment: @J.Pichardo Hm... not sure

Comment: return next.handle just returns the anonymous function, not the intercept function

Comment: Then what do you do when the token expires?